# How to fill in [x]% of a 2d array with the values of another array

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 two-dimensional arrays, one is filled and one is to be filled, both of the same size (n x m). I need to fill in [some random]% of my second array with the exact same values as my first array.
So let's say

```
int[][] arr1 = new int[][] {{0, 1, 0, 1},
                            {1, 0, 1, 0},
                            {0, 0, 1, 1},
                            {1, 1, 0, 0}};
```

I want arr2 to be filled with 25% of arr1's values in the same spot with the other spots just remaining null..

```
int[][] arr2 = new int[4][4];
// where arr2 = something like {{0,1,0,1},
//                              { , , , },
//                              { , , , },
//                              { , , , }}
```

Eventually, the program will call on the user to fill in the missing values, which I can do, just for some reason this part seems to not want to work for me.
This is for a school assignment and the teacher isn't being very helpful with answering questions.

Here's my code:
noting that (variable names are in French..)

1. nbCases = total number of elements in the 2d array
2. nbARemplir = number of elements in the 2nd array to have values assigned to them (based on nbCases * nbPourc where nbPourc is the percentage of the 2nd array to be assigned values)
3. grille[][] = original array
4. gui = second "array" (it's actually a 2d array of JButtons that the teacher wrote..syntax to add a value : gui.setValeur(i, j, value) )

   ```
   int nbCases = grille.length * grille[0].length;
   int nbARemplir = (int)(nbCases * nbPourc);

   do{
       for(int i = 0; i < grille.length; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < grille[i].length; j++) {
               if(rand.nextInt(2) == 1 && nbARemplir > 0) {
                   gui.setValeur(i, j, "" + grille[i][j]);
                   nbARemplir--;
               }
           }
       }       
   } while(nbARemplir > 0);
   ```

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you randomly choose to set the values, you might run through the 2D array multiple times (due to your **while-loop**). Therefore you are likely gonna set a value at the same (i,j) index multiple times, but you are still decrementing **nbARemplir**.

Now, I don't know what type **gui** is, but you could change the if-statement to something like

```java
if(gui[i][j] != null && rand.nextInt(2) == 1 && nbARemplir > 0)...
```

This ensures you are not gonna put in the same value/object twice.

Comment: He said gui is a 2D array of JButtons fyi

Comment: Ye, but it doesn't seem like a normal array, due to this line : `gui.setValeur(i, j, "" + grille[i][j]);`

Comment: it's technically a normal array -- just a 2d array of JButtons in an object (the GUI) named gui.

Comment: the setValeur function is just a setter method .setValeur(x, y, value)
    .setValue(x, y, value) {
        guiArray[x][y] = value;
    }

gui is an object GUI